Build with colcon only up to packages in a given directory?
I have a workspace with multiple repositories checked out, and each repository contains many ROS 2 packages. The packages in a repository can depend on packages in the other two repositories.
For example:

~/ros_ws/src/repository1
~/ros_ws/src/repository2
~/ros_ws/src/repository3

I would like to only build up to the ROS 2 packages contained in a given repository (i.e. ~/ros_ws/src/repository2). If I run colcon build --packages-up-to <repository2 packages>, then I must manually list every package in repository 2. Is there a simpler way to provide an arg to colcon in order to only build up to the packages in repository 2?

Seems like what you need is to make repository2 a metapackage. That way, you can run colcon build --package-select repository2, and it will build everything in repository2.

This is not how colcon build --packages-select-up-to works. It is supposed to build specified packages and their dependencies recursively! I.e.:
package2 depends on package1. Also package3 exists. If you do
colcon build --packages-select-up-to package2

it will build package1 and package2, but not package3. Given your situation, try and find the minimal set of packages in your repository at the end of the build-tree and only build those using packages-up-to <minimal set>.
Also, did you look into the list of colcon build arguments which includes Regex.
To automate building I sometimes have a small sh-script in my ws with specific colcon build commands, if I need a long or complex argument list.

I didn't find --packages-select-up-to available. I only found either packages-up-to or packages-select?
